# save pandas plot with subplots to one file

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am creating subplots in pandas/jupyter notebook from the following dataframe

```
METHOD1       A           B             C              D             E
METHOD2                                                                
high       1410          14           426          13781             1
low       74142         303        757024          95105            37
medium    99174         670        277013         640000           127
mono      46599         207        405108          16793           160

axs = ct.plot(kind='barh', subplots=True, legend=False, figsize=(24,16))
for ax in axs:
    ax.set_xscale('log')
```

In Jupyter I get one image with 4 subplots. I want to save that plot to one png,
but

```
fig=axs.get_figure()
fig.savefig('plot.png')
```

gives an error message

> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'get_figure'

because axs is an array of the subplots
I can save the individual subplots.

How can I save all the subplots to one image?

Answer (score 7):

Do `axs[0].get_figure()`.

You are trying to call a **matplotlib** method on a **numpy** array.

Comment: That's what I figured out indeed.

Comment: What can I say. ;)

Comment: but... the question is in the last sentence, if you know a way to save all the subplots in one (1) image instead of individual plots, that would be more constructive.

Comment: You're using matplotlib. You create a figure (as you probably did), and then you choose to draw things in plots. You either do it in different subplots or in the same one. One subplot means one axis.

You're doing it right as `fig.savefig` saves all the plots/subplots you draw on that fig.